# Display table only to customers with certain tags in shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

Trying to set up visibility of certain elements to customers with certain tags only. 
There are a few tables, originally hidden by display none in main stylesheet. I've created a few separate style sheets to call if tag conditions are met. Yet no luck.

Here is condition code

```
{% if customer.tags contains 'Trade' %}  
{{ table1.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{% endif %}
```

and table1.css (i've put it on top of all other stylesheets)

```
.hiddentable1 {
 display:block !important;
}
```

Comment: You've a syntax error within your example code: `table1.css'` should be `'table1.css'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you could approach this:

1. Add a CSS class to the table to show/hide it depending on whether or not the customer tag exists.

   ```html
   {% assign table1-class = 'table1-hide' %}
   {% if customer.tags contains 'Trade' %}  
       {% assign table1-class = 'table1-show' %}
   {% endif %} 

   <table class="{{ table1-class }}"> ...
   ```
2. Only include the table if the customer tag exists.

   ```html
   {% if customer.tags contains 'Trade' %}  
       {% include 'table1-snippet' %}
   {% endif %}
   ```

Comment: Love the second option, well played!

Comment: ...and to the person who downvoted my answer, please let me know if there's something I can do to improve it. I do not believe my answer is an [egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down). Maybe not as simple a solution as the comment from @hjblok but not incorrect either.